# Subsetting rows selecting on more than one value

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame "H" with columns "HHID" , "Village" and outcome "O"

Village has 5 factors, A, B, C, D, E. However, one of the factor remained unused..for say there are 14 participants recruited from A, 20 from B, 25 from C, 15 from D but none(0) from E. During data entry this factor E was not removed and persisted during the analysis, as data entry was done in SPSS and imported to R using foreign package.

It was fine throughout until I was running the GEE model(from geepack) when I received the following error.

```
fit <- I(O == 1) ~ Village
fit1.1 <- geeglm(fit, family = binomial, id=HHID, data=H)

Factors not allowed to have unused levels...
```

I tried to make a subset of data and ran the model but still get the same error.

```
sub <- H[H$Village %in% c("A", "B","C","D"), ]
```

Just in case that I am not running a wrong model, this is what I have been using

```
fit <- I(O == 1) ~ Village
fit1.1 <- geeglm(fit, family = binomial, id=HHID, data=sub)
```

I don't know how to get rid of this error. Is this basically an error in making the subset.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subset idea won't help because there are no rows where village is not in the set [A, B, C, D]. Instead you need to drop the unused levels in the Village variable:

```
H$Village <- droplevels(H$Village)
```

Note that there is a data.frame method for droplevels, so you can drop all unused levels in all factors in H with

```
H <- droplevels(H)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `?droplevels` to remove unused levels, e.g.:

```
f <- factor(LETTERS[1:4], levels=LETTERS[1:5])
f
#[1] A B C D
#Levels: A B C D E
droplevels(f)
#[1] A B C D
#Levels: A B C D
```

In your case a simple `sub <- droplevels(sub)` should work.